# Parsing error when reading a specific Pajek (NET) file with Networkx into Jupyter

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter, networkx, graph-theory, google-colaboratory

I am trying to reading [this pajek file](http://deim.urv.cat/~alexandre.arenas/data/xarxes/jazz.zip) in Google Colab's version of Jupyter and I get an error when executing the following very simple code:

```
J = nx.MultiDiGraph()
J=nx.read_pajek("/content/data/graphdatasets/jazz.net")
print(nx.info(J))
```

The error is the following:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/networkx/readwrite/pajek.py in parse_pajek(lines)
    211                 except AttributeError:
    212                     splitline = shlex.split(str(l))
--> 213                 id, label = splitline[0:2]
    214                 labels.append(label)
    215                 G.add_node(label)

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

With `pip show networkx`, I see that I'm running Networkx version: 2.3. Am I doing something wrong in the code?

Update: Pasting below the file's first few lines:

```
*Vertices     198
*Arcs
*Edges
       1       8        1
       1      24        1
       1      35        1
       1      42        1
       1      46        1
       1      60        1
       1      74        1
       1      78        1
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Pajek definition](http://vlado.fmf.uni-lj.si/pub/networks/pajek/doc/draweps.htm) the first two lines of your file are not according to the standard. After `*vertices n`, n lines with details about the vertices are expected. In addition, `*edges` and `*arcs` is a duplicate. `NetworkX` assumes use for an edge list, which started with `*arcs` a `MultiDiGraph` and for `*edges` a `MultiGraph` (see current [code](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/networkx-2.3/networkx/readwrite/pajek.py#L231)). To resolve your problem, you only need to delete the first two lines of your `.net`-file.